# Upload image to postimage.org using curl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, curl, upload

I found a script that can upload image to postimage.org using curl. It was posted not long ago, on 2013-09-06, at http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=28867. The simplified script looks like this:

```
curl -Ls -F "upload[]=@$1" -F "adult=no" http://postimage.org/ | grep -Po 'id="code_1".+\Khttp[^<]+'
```

However, when I tried it, it doesn't work any more. I believe it was working when it was posted not long ago, anyone knows how to get it working again please?

**UPDATE:**

Having accepted the answer, I found myself just can't do another successful upload any more:

http://s14.postimg.org/rwbs13uil/screenshot.jpg  http://s12.postimg.org/8rnq0lzc9/screenshot_png_150314.jpg
http://s3.postimg.org/e7r5yhx4f/aequ6_Nei.jpg
http://s1.postimg.org/e3e6pactn/Ohxoh2ae.jpg
http://s27.postimg.org/eh86w1rvz/aequ6_Nei.jpg

I.e., regardless what I tried, I always end up with the above weird image, which is not mine, with wrong image size and wrong image type/extension.

But in fact, the image I was trying to upload is

[image: http://ibin.co/1uoEZfFcgmxE]

So I conclude that there is still something wrong with postimage.org, it's so screwed up that I'll not waste any more of my time on it.

Hm, heck, just want to have a proper conclusion -- I tried to manually upload it via my browser but get exactly the same thing:

http://s27.postimg.org/6qefu76nj/screenshot.jpg

So, **conclusion**, the curl upload is working as expected, only the postimage.org site is screwed. Case closed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
curl -Ls -F "upload[]=@Schermata-11.png" -F "adult=no" http://postimage.org/ | \
  grep -Po 'http[^<]*' | \
  grep "\[" | \
  cut -d "]" -f1 | \
  head -1
```

is working for me :)

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little to explain what this does?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! The posting part is literally the same as mine so I guess it was just a temporarily glitch when I tried it. http://s29.postimg.org/6y05a8ccl/screenshot.png . Your grepping part doesn't work for me, but that's not the point of OP. As long as the posting part works, I'm happy! +1

Answer (score 2):

The probable reason why it doesn't work anymore is because it's a hack.

> Note: this is a hack and will probably break next time postimage change their front page. (Please post if you find a problem.) At that time it will have to be rehacked, or maybe changed to imgur which has a proper api, but needs registration.